# Handlebars validate button submit

Tags: template, handlebars.js

Olá,

preciso fazer uma verificação usando handlebars...

após clicar no botão cadastrar , caso seja bem sucedido o cadastro, exibe uma modal

caso contrario o usuário é forçado a preencher os campos,

porem eu só quero exibir o modal se o submit for feito...

estou usando uma lógica de onclick, entao toda vez que clica no botão ....

mesmo que dê erro no formulário o modal é exibido ...

alguém sabe se via handlebars consigo resolver esse problema com if else? ou vou ter que trabalhar a logica em JS

Segue o código a seguir:

JavaScript

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Html

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desde já agradeço

Comment: Com handlebars dá também, desde que vc mande algo do back-end para validar, acho mais fácil fazer isso no front com javascript, agora tem que ver o que deseja fazer, pois quando vc submete o form você automaticamente é redirecionado, acho que não vai dar pra fazer como quer fazer!

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o problema usando addEventListenet('submit');

porém será que no handlebars seria possível ?

desde já agradeço